# Qt: how do I open a text file from desktop in my qt program?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, file, desktop

I want to be able to double click on a text file on the desktop, or select my application via window's open with..., and have that file be opened in my application, whether or not my application is already running. How do I do this?

Comment: You have to write to the Windows registry.

Comment: [assoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When opened with Windows, Windows will pass the text file path as argument to your application. This path can be retrieved in `QCoreApplication::arguments()`.

To open it if the application is already running, there are certainly many solutions. This one is maybe not the nicest and not the simplest, but should work.

1. Your application will be started a 2nd time anyway I think. But you can detect that, either by using the Windows API, or by calling "tasklist.exe" in a QProcess, reading the result and checking whether you find your application name.exe in the returned text. If yes, you should tell the first instance to open the file, and then quit the 2nd instance.
2. To tell your first instance to open that file from the 2nd instance, you need to talk between your different instances. One way to do that may be to use a QUdpSocket. If step 1. tells you that no other instance is running, then it is your main instance, so you create a QUdpSocket and listen of a defined local port (e.g. 12345) for a message containing the file to open. Otherwise, if it is your 2nd instance, you create a QUdpSocket and write to the local port defined above, and then you quit. In the first instance, when you receive a packet (=datagram) containing a file to open, you open it.